# Need help in creating a CLI app with poetry

Tags: python, command-line-interface, packaging

i've created a cli app in python using typer but instead of calling `py main.py` i want to call the program by using the command `starfish`. In past i've created and published cli apps using poetry packaging but this time i am facing issues.

**pyproject.toml**

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "starfish"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A python based File Transfer Protocol(FTP) program."
authors = ["777advait"]
license = "MIT License"
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
rich = "^13.3.4"
questionary = "^1.10.0"
bcrypt = "^4.0.1"
typer = "^0.7.0"
scapy = "^2.5.0"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
starfish="starfish.main:run"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

following image shows the issue that im facing
[image: issue]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
poetry run starfish
```

or enter the poetry venv with `poetry shell` then just `starfish`